# MS Access VBA Nested loop error handling. I need to do different error handling in each nested loop. How does it work?

Tags: ms-access

I have VBA code written to create a Nacha file for multiple states and reporting entities.  There are 3 nested loops to create and write to the file, each one writing a line to the nacha file and updating the block counts, line counts, and total dollar amounts.  I need to do different error handling within each loop due to the writing of the records to the file.  If something errors in the addenda record, i need to remove the prior written line for the detail record and update the counts/amounts. Can I put On Error GoTo inside a loop and that stops once outside the loop?  What I would like to do is shown below.

```
Function MyStuff()
Do While Not batch.EOF
        On Error GoTo BatchError
        Do Something
        write to file

        Do While Not EntryDetail.EOF
                On Error GoTo EntryError
                Do Something
                Write to File
                'Update Values for counts and dollars

                Do While Not Addenda.EOF
                        On Error GoTo AddendaError
                        Do Something
                        Write to File
                        'Update Values for counts and dollars
                        Loop
                Loop
        'Update Values for Counts and Dollars
         Loop
End Function

BatchError:
        'handle errors
        Resume Next

EntryError:
        'handle errors
        Resume Next
AddendaError:
        'Handle Errors
        Resume Next
```

If do it this way, will the error handling revert back to the prior loop once the current loop ends?  So if an error happens in the addenda loop, it will go to the AddendaError handling and when that loop ends, it will revert to the EntryError handler and then when that loop ends it will revert to the BatchError handler?

Comment: You should remove all the "Do Something" outside the loop. If these are longwinded, write to a temp table. Then export - if you can open the file and write the first line, it is extremely unlikely, than an error should occur during writing of the rest of the file.

Answer (score 0):

`On Error GoTo` doesn't know anything about loops. The last one encountered will be active. If you want to revert to the previous one after a loop, you must call it again. E.g.

```vb
Function MyStuff()
    Do While Not batch.EOF
        On Error GoTo BatchError
        Do Something
        write to file

        Do While Not EntryDetail.EOF
            On Error GoTo EntryError
            Do Something
            Write to File
            'Update Values for counts and dollars

            Do While Not Addenda.EOF
                On Error GoTo AddendaError
                Do Something
                Write to File
                'Update Values for counts and dollars
            Loop

            On Error GoTo EntryError '<<<<<< repeat here! =================
            'Do Entry stuff
        Loop
        On Error GoTo BatchError '<<<<<< repeat here! =====================
        'Do Batch stuff
    Loop
    Exit Function '<<<<< Do not forget before error handling! =============

BatchError:
    'handle errors
    Resume Next

EntryError:
    'handle errors
    Resume Next

AddendaError:
    'Handle Errors
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Also, do not forget `Exit Function` before the Error handling labels!

`End Function` comes at the very end.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll give it a try.  And I do have an "Exit Function" before my error handling, just forgot to put it in my code example.

Comment: I know someone is going to comment "ask another question" but how can I force the next loop instead of doing resume next in the error handler?

Comment: You can also use `On Error Resume Next` inside the loop and when an error is encountered, the next statement will be executed. You can then test whether there was an error with `If Err.Number = 0 Then <no error> Else <error> End If` and get the message with `Err.Description` and clear the error with `Err.Clear`. But you could also set a Boolean flag in the error handlers and then test for that one in the loops and do `Exit Do` to leave the loop or check the flag in the loop condition.